# Tcl/Tk: How can I ignore newlines when creating a list from a column of data?

Tags: list, tcl

I have a single column of data that contains the names of items that I'd like to store in a Tcl list.  For the purposes of readability, I'd like to leave each item on its own line (in this case, it will make future editing of the script a lot easier for those that follow me).  How can I wrap my column of data in Tcl commands/syntax so that it simply takes the item on each line and forms a Tcl list?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
set mylist {
   apples
   bananas
   peaches
   cherries
}
```

What I was hoping for is

```
% puts $mylist
apples bananas peaches cherries
%
```

What I get is

```
% puts $mylist

apples
bananas
peaches
cherries

%
```

Also, the length of the actual returned list is 1, which is obviously not what I desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some prefer an idiom using the [`{*}` expansion operator](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/%7B%2A%7D), nicely avoiding backslashes:

```
% set mylist [list {*}{
   apples
   bananas
   peaches
   cherries
}]
apples bananas peaches cherries
% puts $mylist
apples bananas peaches cherries
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a string that would be perfectly accepted as a list, if you used any list commands on it. For example: `llength $mylist` would produce 4. (Not 1 as you reported. I guess you may have inadvertedly done `llength mylist`)

If you want to print the string as a canonical list, i.e. you want string -> list -> string conversion, you have to do something to force the conversion to a list. One way would be to use `puts [join $mylist]`. The join command takes a list, so this would convert $mylist to a list and then back to a string.

If you want the mylist variable to actually contain the list in cananical form, you can use one of the following commands on it:

```
set mylist [lassign $mylist]

set mylist [lrange $mylist 0 end]
```

But most of the time, the way you defined the list is perfectly fine for normal use.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the most simple way to do that:

```
% set mylist [list \
apples \
bananas \
peaches \
cherries \
]

% puts $mylist
apples bananas peaches cherries
```